# Turning Regular Select Statements Into Correlated Subquery?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, correlated-subquery

I have my following SQL query:

```
 SELECT name, transaction_id, MIN(transaction_date)
 FROM clients
 JOIN transactions ON clients.client_id = transactions.client_id
 GROUP BY name, transaction_id;
```

That I'd like to turn into a **correlated subquery** with the following structure:

```
 SELECT a, b, MIN(c)
 FROM t1
 JOIN t2 ON t1.d = t2.d
 WHERE c IN
      (SELECT * 
      FROM t2
      HAVING....)
```

Where `a, b, c` are column-names and `t1, t2` are tables.

But I'm having difficulty in the process.

For reference, the original problem is asking to return the earliest transaction_date of each customer along with its corresponding transaction_id.

So, if the `transactions` table had the following:

```
   transaction_id    client_id      transaction_date
         1               1              02-02-17
         2               1              02-01-17
         3               2              02-03-17
         4               2              02-04-17
```

The correlated subquery would return:

```
    name       transaction_id       transaction_date
    John            2                   02-01-17
    Mary            3                   02-03-17
```

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a correlated subquery?

Comment: It's part of the requirement from the original problem.  I figured out how to do it in the regular select statement, I'm just having problems turning it into a correlate subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not do what you think it does. A proper query would be:

```
SELECT c.name, t.transaction_id, t.transaction_date
FROM clients c JOIN
     transactions t
     ON c.client_id = t.client_id
WHERE t.transaction_date = (SELECT MIN(t2.transaction_date)
                            FROM transactions t2
                            WHERE t2.client_id = t.client_id
                           );
```

A more typical query would be:

```
SELECT name, transaction_id, transaction_date
FROM (SELECT c.name, t.transaction_id, t.transaction_date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.client_id ORDER BY t.transaction_date) as seqnum
      FROM clients c JOIN
           transactions t
           ON c.client_id = t.client_id 
     ) ct
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: the t2.ctransaction_date is different from the t.transaction_date right?  Why do we need to make a "second" t2.transaction_date?

Comment: @5120bee . . . You don't, if you use `row_number()`.

Comment: I haven't heard of that function yet.  What does `row_number()` do?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle 12c there are `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` clauses:
(look for `cross_outer_apply_clause` in [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJHDDA)):

> **cross_outer_apply_clause**
>
> This clause allows you to perform a variation of an ANSI CROSS JOIN or
>   an ANSI LEFT OUTER JOIN **with left correlation support**. You can specify
>   a table_reference or collection_expression to the right of the APPLY
>   keyword. The table_reference can be a table, inline view, or TABLE
>   collection expression. The collection_expression can be a subquery, a
>   column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its
>   form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is
>   nested table or varray. The table_reference or collection_expression
>   can reference columns of tables defined in the FROM clause to the left
>   of the APPLY keyword. **This is called left correlation**.

These two clauses have a **(left) correlation support** - this simply means that correlated subqueries can be used.
Your query might look like this:

```
select c.*, x.*
from clients c
cross apply (
   select transaction_id, transaction_date
   from transactions t
   where t.client_id = c.client_id
   order by transaction_date desc
   fetch first row only
) x
```

or using `outer apply`:

```
select c.*, x.*
from clients c
outer apply (
   select transaction_id, transaction_date
   from transactions t
   where t.client_id = c.client_id
   order by transaction_date desc
   fetch first row only
) x
```

The latter query is like `LEFT JOIN` - it gives all clients including clients that have no any transaction, while the former one is like `INNER JOIN` and lists only clients that have at least 1 transaction.
Both queries use correlated subqueries on the right side, 
these subqueries use `where t.client_id = c.client_id` condition which references a table on the left side.